# Google compute engine apache2 connection refused

Tags: apache, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to configure an Apache web server on the Google Cloud platform, in a compute engine instance. My problem is, that I can not reach my web server.

In the VPC network, if I open all the ports, then I get connection refused. If I only open the TCP 80 port, then I get connection timeout. I tried to delete the instance and start a new, the result is the same. With the default http rules I also get connection refused.

Firewall setting on the Google Cloud platform:
[image: Firewall setting on the Google Cloud platform]

Info from the VM instance:
[image: dsffds]
[image: fdsasd]

Answer (score 1):

Oh, guys, sorry for a spam question. I just wasn't paying enough attention. On the VM instances page I clicked on the external IP, and it opened a page. But it tried to connect through https instead of http.

Answer (score 0):

you need to assign an external IP... in order to access from a public network.

because `10.0.0.0` – `10.255.255.255` is a private class A range.